# Edit a string inside a compiled exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm working with Visual studio c++ inside windows.

What I want to do is to search for a specific string inside a compiled exe and replace it with another one.

It's possible using notepad++ but i want to do my own exe that does that.

Example :

1. search inside blabla.exe for string "test1"
2. replace it with another string "test2"
3. save

What's the easiest way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Hex Editor, [Hxd](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)(http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) can make it easily

Comment: Is this possible to be done through an application i compile in c++  and not using an external editor ?

Comment: Yes, it is easy by coding. You must open file as binary file(like fopen("file", "rb+"); then read to buffer, and replace the string. Important, you must replace with a so long string. ("abc" ==> "aaa")